# lisiting all PIDs

Tags: linux, bash, process

```
ps -ax
PID 

1    
2
. 
.
.
1549
1564 
1569 

.
.
1716
1730 
1759
```

Is there any way that I can generate the process PIDS in decending order ie userlevel process ,system level process and then strace them

```
PID
1759 
1730
1716
.
.
2
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `k` modifier in order to specify the sorting order.  Saying:

```
 ps axk-pid
```

would sort the output by decreasing PIDs.

From `man ps`:

```
   k spec          Specify sorting order. Sorting syntax is
                   [+|-]key[,[+|-]key[,...]]. Choose a multi-letter key
                   from the STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS section. The "+"
                   is optional since default direction is increasing
                   numerical or lexicographic order. Identical to --sort.
                   Examples:
                   ps jaxkuid,-ppid,+pid
                   ps axk comm o comm,args
                   ps kstart_time -ef
```

Moreover, you can use the `-o` option in order to control which column is displayed.  Saying:

```
ps axk-pid -o pid
```

would display only the process ID.